# Error cannot find symbol via online compiler only

Tags: java

I am receiving this error when I submit my code. This only happens when I submit my code on an online compiler necessary for my course, however, when I run my code via InteliJ it compiles properly.

> Main.java:335: error: cannot find symbol
>           while (!(TeamMember.contains("Stop"))){
>                              ^
>     symbol:   method contains(String)
>     location: class TeamMember
>   1 error
>   <

My classes are as follows:

Main:

```
package com.company;

 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "";
    String id = "";

    ArrayList<TeamMember> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!(TeamMember.contains("Stop"))) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the id: ");
        id = scan.nextLine();

        list.add(new TeamMember(name.toLowerCase(), id));

        System.out.println(Main.selectionSort(list));


    }
    int size = list.size();
    for (int j = size; j > (list.size() + 2); j--) {
        list.remove(j);
    }

}

public static ArrayList<TeamMember> selectionSort(ArrayList<TeamMember> list) {
    TeamMember[] teamArray = new TeamMember[list.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        teamArray[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < teamArray.length - 1; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < teamArray.length; j++) {
            if (teamArray[j].compareTo(teamArray[minIndex]) < 0) {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        TeamMember holder = teamArray[i];
        teamArray[i] = teamArray[minIndex];
        teamArray[minIndex] = holder;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, teamArray[i]);
    }

    return list;
}

}
```

TeamMember:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class TeamMember{
private String fullName;
private String idString;

public TeamMember(String name, String id){
    fullName = "";
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    String [] charName = new String[name.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < charName.length; i++){
        charName[i] = Character.toString(name.charAt(i));
        if(i == 0){
            charName[0] = charName[0].toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < charName.length - 1; i++){
        if(charName[i].equals(" ") && !charName[i + 1].equals(" ")){
            charName[i + 1] = charName[i + 1].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < charName.length; i++){
        fullName = fullName + charName[i];
    }

    idString = id;
}

public static boolean contains(String stop) {
return false;
}

public String getID(){
    return idString;
}

public String toString(){
    return fullName;
}

public int compareTo(TeamMember other){
    if(idString.compareTo(other.getID()) < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(idString.compareTo(other.getID()) > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Both the classes are present in the separate files or in the same file?

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava Seperate files

Comment: It builds at https://paiza.io/projects/4cFfipxMgUWjBCqhnbj9EQ?language=java . Are you sure you copied exact code to online compiler ? Main.java doesn't even have line 335.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like class `TeamMember` is not accessible from your `Main` class. Try this code as it should work having the classes in the same file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main 
{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "";
    String id = "";

    ArrayList<TeamMember> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!(TeamMember.contains("Stop"))) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter the id: ");
        id = scan.nextLine();

        list.add(new TeamMember(name.toLowerCase(), id));

        System.out.println(Main.selectionSort(list));


    }
    int size = list.size();
    for (int j = size; j > (list.size() + 2); j--) {
        list.remove(j);
    }

}

public static ArrayList<TeamMember> selectionSort(ArrayList<TeamMember> list) {
    TeamMember[] teamArray = new TeamMember[list.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        teamArray[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < teamArray.length - 1; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < teamArray.length; j++) {
            if (teamArray[j].compareTo(teamArray[minIndex]) < 0) {
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        TeamMember holder = teamArray[i];
        teamArray[i] = teamArray[minIndex];
        teamArray[minIndex] = holder;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.set(i, teamArray[i]);
    }

    return list;
}

}

class TeamMember{
private String fullName;
private String idString;

public TeamMember(String name, String id){
    fullName = "";
    name = name.toLowerCase();
    String [] charName = new String[name.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < charName.length; i++){
        charName[i] = Character.toString(name.charAt(i));
        if(i == 0){
            charName[0] = charName[0].toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < charName.length - 1; i++){
        if(charName[i].equals(" ") && !charName[i + 1].equals(" ")){
            charName[i + 1] = charName[i + 1].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < charName.length; i++){
        fullName = fullName + charName[i];
    }

    idString = id;
}

public static boolean contains(String stop) {
return false;
}

public String getID(){
    return idString;
}

public String toString(){
    return fullName;
}

public int compareTo(TeamMember other){
    if(idString.compareTo(other.getID()) < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else if(idString.compareTo(other.getID()) > 0){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```